# Getting Facebook / Twitter's friend's Location for Foursquare in iPhone .

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, twitter, foursquare

I am making an application which uses foursquare in the application ,

Now I want to get my facebook and twitter friends in the application , so that if any friend is nearby me than I can see their annotation on the Map . I am not sure if I get the list of my friends/ follower and their location in the map .

is their any possible way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your friends from these other networks are also friends with you on foursquare, you will be able to receive their most recent public checkin using the /checkins/recent endpoint detailed at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/recent.

If they are not yet friends with you on foursquare, you can use the /users/search endpoint detailed at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/search to find those users you are friends with on Facebook or follow on Twitter who also have foursquare accounts. You will have to have your user send them friend requests and the other user will have to accept the request, but then they will show up on /checkins/recent.

Foursquare does not provide a way to see the location of a user with whom you are not friends, so you won't be able to get at their location without friending them first.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible to do as it would break open some serious privacy issues.